# ExtJS 3.* line chart axis label rotate

Tags: extjs, linechart

How can I rotate ExtJS line chart x-axis' label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extraStyle: {
     xAxis: {
         labelRotation: 45         //-90 through 90 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a display property for the label which specifies the presence and position of labels for each pie slice. Either "rotate", "middle", "insideStart", "insideEnd", "outside", "over", "under", or "none" to prevent label rendering. Default value: 'none'.

link for ref: [Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Line)

Comment: These are for ExtJS 4.* I think. I couldn't found for 3.* version in API page.

Comment: would let you know once i get it.